# Set/force HUE Interface language to english (Hadoop/Cloudera)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

For some reason the hue interface language is German when I access it from my machine.

(German language settings, but english browser and Operating system)

How can I force hue to always display english?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hue is taking the preferred locale sent by your browser. The German locale in your browser is probably set with higher priority than the English one.

[This article](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php#changing) explains where you can change it.